# How to write react test cases for nested components using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, web-frontend, react-testing-library

I have a component AdminDashboard which renders two other components in it - LeaderBoard and ActivityList

How do I write test cases for this component using react testing library?
My test file is giving me a 50% coverage.
I want a 100% coverage on this

```
import React from 'react';
import LeaderBoard from '../LeaderBoard/LeaderBoard';
import ActivitiesList from '../ActivitiesList/ActivitiesList';

function AdminDashboard(props) {
    return (
        <div >
            <LeaderBoard />
            <ActivitiesList assigned={props.assigned} rows = {props.rows} getData = {props.getData} deleteActivity={(data)=>props.deleteActivity(data)}></ActivitiesList>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AdminDashboard;
```

My AdminDashboard.test.js :

```
it("renders without crashing", ()=>{

    let assigned = [// dummy data];
    let rows = [ // dummy data];
    const getData = () => {

    }
    const deleteActivity = (activityId) => {

    }

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<AdminDashboard assigned={assigned} rows={rows} getData={getData} deleteActivity={(data) => deleteActivity(data)}/>,div);
})

it("matches snapshot", () => {

    let assigned = [ //dummy data ];
    let rows = [ //dummy data ];
    const getData = () => {

    }
    const deleteActivity = (activityId) => {

    }

    const tree = renderer.create(<AdminDashboard assigned={assigned} rows={rows} getData={getData} deleteActivity={(data) => deleteActivity(data)}/>).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```